# convert mp4 from x264enc to rgb 24 bits with gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I have generated successfully an .mp4 file with gstreamer with the following command line:

```
gst-launch -v filesrc location=Tears.avi ! decodebin2 ! ffmpegcolorspace! x264enc ! qtmux ! filesink location=result.mp4
```

There is no audio.

Now, I'd like to convert result.mp4 into an avi file based on video/x-raw-rgb.

I'm not yet familiar with gstreamer.

Answer (score 0):

```
gst-launch filesrc location=result.mp4 ! decodebin2 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! video/x-raw-rgb ! avimux ! filesink location=result-rgb.avi
```

Although be warned, raw videos will be huge.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.

gst-inspect avimux gives:
SINK template: 'video_%d'
    Availability: On request
      Has request_new_pad() function: gst_avi_mux_request_new_pad
    Capabilities:
      video/x-raw-yuv
bla bla...

I do not see that avimux sink is compatible with video/x-raw-rgb.

I have tested your solution and it does not work at the moment.

I have a soltution to convert h264 file to yuv file:
gst-launch -t -v filesrc location=result.mp4 ! qtdemux ! ffdec_h264 ! video/x-raw-yuv ! avimux ! filesink location=result-yuv.avi

The problem is I need an rgb avi output file...

No idea...?

Thanks for your help,

Thierry